# Unable to read files Uri shared by other app i.e. Whatsapp

Tags: android, uri, deep-linking, android-fileprovider, share-intent

When file is shared by other apps via FileProvider then the Uri received in my app is not readable. If i try to get file path or create file from it then it says file doesn't exist. The sample Uri is from whatsapp is **content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/91836** . It gives Security exception when i try to read bitmap from the Uri.

Code lines is onCreate method:

```
Uri mediaUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), mediaUri);
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <!--<data android:mimeType="video/*" />-->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.whatsapp.MediaProvider from ProcessRecord{fbda37f 23891:com.fayvo/u0a273} (pid=23891, uid=10273) that is not exported from UID 10133
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6759)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2912)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1879)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1460)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1313)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1033)
        at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:919)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include how you are getting the `Uri` and where you are trying to use the `Uri`. Bear in mind that [by default only the activity that receives the `Uri` can use it](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: updated the code line, simply I share the picture from whatsapp chat and it doesn't load in my app

Comment: If those two lines are sequential (e.g., in `onCreate()` of your `ACTION_VIEW` activity), and you are getting the `Uri` as shown from `EXTRA_STREAM`, then this would appear to be a bug in WhatsApp.

Comment: But how other apps are working fine with it. My same code is working fine when i share the image from external storage of whatsapp. The issue seems with the uri that seems private in this case.

Comment: "But how other apps are working fine with it" -- I cannot answer that. There may be bugs in your implementation, but we only have the two lines of code to look at, so it will be difficult for anyone to give you more specific advice.

Comment: added further details, didn't post complete file as it will be messy and the main part of code that is handling the action is easy to read for viewers.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue

Comment: @MarcoDuindam I've added the method in the answer to this question, this worked for me in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Using this method worked for me in those cases:

```
private File readSharedContentUri(Uri contentUri) {
    // Get content resolver.
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    File targetFile = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        targetFile = PathUtil.getFilePath(context, true, "received_media_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), CommonUtils.isMimeTypeOfImage(contentResolver.getType(contentUri)) ? ".jpg" : ".mp4");
        inputStream.close();
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        outStream.write(buffer);
        outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return targetFile;
}
```

Comment: What is PathUtil &  CommonUtils?? It is not able to find.

Comment: it is just a util class to create a file object. You can replace this line with your desired file path.